# How does one dynamically resize arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, resize

I'm trying to read an unknown number of elements into the array, when my size reaches the current capacity, I call a function to double the size and copy the contents of the old array into a new array. I got my '&' but it seems it's still passing the array by value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void resize(int*&, int&);

int main() {
    ifstream in("numbers.input");
    int cap = 10;
    double avg;
    int total = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int *arr = new int [cap];
    int temp;

    for(int i =0; i <cap; i++){
        in >> temp;
        if(size >= cap) {
            resize(arr,cap);
        }
        arr[i]=temp;
        total += arr[i];
        size++;
    }
    avg = (double) total/cap;
    cout << cap <<endl;
    cout << size <<endl;
    cout << total <<endl;
    cout << avg;
    return 0;

}
void resize(int *&arr,int &cap) {
    cap*=2;
    int* newArr = new int[cap];
    for(int i = 0; i < cap; i++){
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    delete [] arr;
    arr = newArr;
}
```

Comment: Why is it so hard to format code before posting...

Comment: Use vector and avoid the problem?

Comment: What evidence do you have that the "array" (actually the pointer) is not being passed by reference? It doesn't take an example this complicated to verify that statement.

Comment: Arrays can't be passed by value, so your observation is incorrect.

Comment: Here's a more minimal example that tests your assertion that `arr` is passed by value: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7839b259381c1d13

Comment: If you have to use an array, then pass a pointer to the first element, like you normally do anyway.

Comment: You have a bug in the for loop that does the copying in the call to `resize`.  Can you spot it?

Comment: ^To be more specific, you are going out of bounds of your old array in the `resize` function.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you try to implement 'by hand' is already in
the standard library.  Use std::vector<> which implements
a doubling/reallocation strategy very similar to what you're 
proposing.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in("numbers.input");
    std::vector<int> arr;
    int temp;
    while (in >> temp) { arr.push_back(temp); }

    // process your data ...
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

To answer the question more literally:  Arrays are always passed
by reference, typically by passing a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Consider editing the title of your question?  It's really about dynamic resizing of an array.

Comment: I'd use vector if I could, but the assignment calls for an array. But thanks, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Your resize function is taking the pointer by reference and will modify the value of the variable it is called with. However you have a number of bugs:

1. You copy `cap` items out of the old array, but you have already doubled `cap`, leading to an out of bound access and a possible crash.
2. Your `resize` function never gets called, due to a bug in your input loop. **You should step through in a debugger** (or at least add some trace cout calls) to work out what is going on. Try to figure this one out, if you can't let me know.
3. Your average is using `cap` as the divisor, that is not correct.

Note: You should add in your question that you can't use `vector`, because that would be the normal way to do this.

Note 2: In your question, you should also say exactly what is going wrong with your program - "seems to be passing the array by value" is a bit vague - why do you think it isn't passing by value?

Comment: There is another issue.  Changing the value of `cap` prematurely in the `resize` function before `new[]` is called.  If `new[]` throws an exception, `cap` now has a wrong value.

Comment: Well, I think it is passing it by value because the array remains unchanged, but as you pointed out, the function to modify it, isn't even being called. Nonetheless, you've pointed me in the right direction and I really appreciate it.

Comment: I got it to call resize now. However, I think an exception is being thrown for running out of memory(std::bad_alloc), but I'm confused. Shouldn't new and delete protect me from that?

Comment: It depends on how you changed your loop. If you changed the condition to something like `i < cap+1`, then it will never stop because `i` will never exceed `cap`. You will then keep doubling `cap` until it gets too big to allocate. Use a loop like in the other answer, where the loop will stop when the input finishes.